# How can I display an image and a table side by side

Tags: html

I cant seem to have a logo and a table side by side but not very close to each other. The only way I've been able to achieve this is using a table, but the image and the table become very close to each other. I want to the table in the middle of the page, and the logo between the table and the far end of the left screen.

like this

logo  table

this is how it is right now

logo

---table

```
<div id="header" style="height:15%;width:100%;">
    <img src="/e-com/images/logo.jpg" style="margin-left:15%;margin-top:5%"/>
    <table border="1" width="44" style="margin-left:30%;float:top;"> 
    <tr>
            <td><h1><a href="home">Home</a></h1></td>
            <td><h1><a href="home">Home</a></h1></td>
            <td><h1><a href="home">Home</a></h1></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use two div and set to float left

```
<div id="header" style="height:15%;width:100%;">
    <div style='float:left'>
        <img src="/e-com/images/logo.jpg" style="margin-left:15%;margin-top:5%"/>
    </div>
    <div style='float:leftt'>
        <table border="1" width="44" style="margin-left:30%;float:top;"> 
            <tr>
                <td><h1><a href="home">Home</a></h1></td>
                <td><h1><a href="home">Home</a></h1></td>
                <td><h1><a href="home">Home</a></h1></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: having one of them float left and the other right placed them all the way at the far left and right of the screen. But at least they were on the same level, so I changed the table to float right.

Comment: For the future readers i have edited the answer to align image and Headers to left

Answer (score 1):

1) Don't use tables for layouts. Learn how to use FLOATS.

2) Use a CSS background image for your logo. UI elements (that are not page content) should be CSS backgrounds, not inline images.

Assuming your logo is 100 x 100 (adjust accordingly):

```
.logoContainer {
      background-image:url(../yourimage.png);
      background-repeat:no-repeat
      padding-left:100px;
      min-height:100px;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be an easy way to get u going for what ur trying to achieve..

http://jsfiddle.net/8NDZP/

```
<div style='float:left'>
    <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/Moscow_July_2011-7a.jpg/325px-Moscow_July_2011-7a.jpg'>
</div>
<div style='float:right'>
    <table border="1" width="44" style="margin-left:30%;float:top;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <h1><a href="home">Home</a></h1>

            </td>
            <td>
                 <h1><a href="home">Home</a></h1>

            </td>
            <td>
                 <h1><a href="home">Home</a></h1>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```